# In react re-rendering, how to prevent resetting of the scrollbar to topmost point of other non-changed components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I have the following sample react code

```
const A = () => {
    const [value1, setValue1] = React.useState(true);
    const [value2, setValue2] = React.useState(true);

    return (
    <div>
        <div class="first-comp">
             <FirstComponent data1={value1} data2={value2} />
        </div>
        <div class="second-comp">
             <SecondComponent onChange={() => {setValue1(false); setValue2(false);}} />
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

When the `SecondComponent` is calling `onChange`, then both "first-comp" and "second-comp" are being re-rendered on the screen.

Since on re-rendering of `SecondComponent`, my scroll is resetting (i.e. If I had scrolled the internal scrollbar down in SecondComponent, on rerendering the SecondComponent renders at the top and not at the point where I had last scrolled to)

Is there a way that, when onChange changes the stateVariables, the `<SecondComponent />` does not get re-rendered or the scroll does not get disturbed in SecondComponent or somehow the scroll gets preserved?

Comment: There is no reason your scroll is reset, maybe provide code of your <SecondComponent> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that on changing the state using setValue, react was running the UI of the second component.

Using shouldComponentUpdate() as mentioned here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-shouldcomponentupdate-method/
or use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to prevent this re-rendering

I configured  to not update when the value1 & value2 changes